# Rails way of constructing & redirecting to an url with post parameters of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I would like to do that's the best way of actually accomplishing the 
following on Rails.

I have a "Booking Form" with 5 fields (Property, Amount of Children, 
Amount of Adults and 2 Dates - Departure and Arrival) based on these 
fields, I need to construct an URL and redirect the user to this url. 
Now, I have 2 questions.

1) How i catch the POST parameters in the controller, because I'm 
mapping the form to an action like this:

```
<% form_tag(:action => "booking") do %>
```

and routing it to a controller action like this: (Pages Controller, 
Booking Action)

```
match 'pages/booking' => 'pages#booking'
```

2) Is this the Rails way of actually accomplishing such thing? 
I did it this way in PHP in the past, but now I have the need of 
actually doing it in Rails, could you Rails Gurus inspire me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access parameters in the controller, even ones submitted in a POST body, use the `params` hash.  Eg: `params[:form_field]`

To redirect to another URL using a controller, use `redirect_to`.  You can certainly use the values in `params` to construct a URL and pass it to `redirect_to`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using resourceful routes, which is the best way to go about such things, you would route things through the traditional approach:

```
resources :bookings
```

Then you'd post the form to `bookings_path` and it would all work out, as that's `BookingsController#create`. It's always better to have a strong correlation between model and controller where possible.

The `resources` definition in `routes.rb` helps you by creating all the default RESTful actions which you can build off of. If you really need a custom route, you can always rename it using the `:as` option, or route it independently.

If you go about creating your own arbitrary routes, such as `/pages/booking` you're going to create quite a mess that someone else will have to maintain. Quite often that someone else is you in the future.

Comment: I know all this, the only reason why I had to add it like this, I't because I'm  using a Rails CMS called refinery, but my question is not about routes and whatnot, but rather the best (or optimal) way/s to handle URL construction and redirect in a controller.

Comment: That wasn't clear in the question. Sounded like you were doing it the PHP way and wanted to know if there was a more standard method. The optimal way is to adhere as closely as possible to convention even if you can, theoretically, do all kinds of things. If you set it up as a regular action, you'll get through all your POST variables in the usual `params` hash. Even using a CMS you should be able to create your own controllers.